# Reading files of Ubuntu Home from Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8, data-recovery

I had dual OS. I today tried to upgrade Ubuntu to 14.10 but due to error at the process, my Ubuntu doesn't open. I tried to recover Ubuntu but had no luck. I had important project file in the home of Ubuntu, but apparently I cannot access those from Windows 8.1.

How can I get those files? Please help me. I am in real trouble :-(

**Edited**

I have perfectly working windows but Ubuntu doesn't start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already have been able to access an Ext4 partition from windows with a driver like [Ext2FS for windows](http://www.ext2fsd.com/) .

The problem you have here is that Microsoft decided not to implement other filesystems than NTFS, FAT16, FAT32 and maybe some other old and bad FS.

Comment: Can you help me with this? So apparently it is possible?

Comment: @Nabin, just install the driver from the above link.

Comment: @GauravJoseph Perfect. Thank you. I can see all the directories.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be a to run Ubuntu from a USB or DVD -https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCD

Comment: Won't this remove my files? Isn't it similar to the installing new OS?

Comment: @Nabin,no this runs the OS from RAM.

Comment: Thanks for the help @GauravJoseph. I had to recover files. And Jonride's answer made it possible. And will try your suggestion too. I think it's the way to recover the Ubuntu itself. Right?